# LaTeX error for siunitx in a longtable environment

Tags: tables, pdftex, siunitx, emacs, auctex

I've been working on a large document which makes frequent use of `\include{}`ed `longtable` environments and `siunitx`. Recently, longer expressions using `siunitx` have been causing compile errors which I have been unable to solve. It is entirely likely that another issue is manifesting itself within these `siunitx` expressions, but I have not been able to figure out the exact issue.

I am using `texlive` on `archlinux` with `emacs` and `auctex` as my editing environment.

`main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

%PACKAGES
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}%si unit typesetting
\usepackage{amsmath}%math typesetting stuff
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%header & footer stuff
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}%page margins & stuff
%\usepackage{multicol}%multicolumn stuff in tables

\usepackage{url}%nice url typesetting
\usepackage{textcomp}%used for \textrangle & similar--adds symbols for text environment
\usepackage{graphicx}%for pictures and stuff

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}%adds additional table commands (\toprule, etc.)
\usepackage{longtable}%handles tables spanning multiple pages

\usepackage{hyperref}%adds pdf hyperlinks for document references (e.g., table of contents)

%SIUNITX STUFF
\let\DeclareUSUnit\DeclareSIUnit
\let\US\SI
\let\us\si%means of separating SI and US units
%us unit declarations
\DeclareUSUnit\inch{in}
\DeclareUSUnit\foot{ft}
\DeclareUSUnit\pound{lb}
\DeclareUSUnit\mile{mi}
\DeclareUSUnit\gallon{gal}
\DeclareUSUnit\horsepower{hp}
\DeclareUSUnit\britishthermalunit{Btu}%british thermal unit
\DeclareUSUnit\slug{slug}
%si unit declarations
\DeclareSIUnit\atmosphere{atm}
\DeclareSIUnit\year{y}
\DeclareSIUnit\lightspeed{c}
\DeclareSIUnit\lightyear{ly}
\DeclareSIUnit\dyne{dyn}
\DeclareSIUnit\ergon{erg}
\DeclareSIUnit\calorie{cal}
\DeclareSIUnit\revolution{rev}
\DeclareSIUnit\gauss{G}
%siunitx setup stuff
\sisetup{inter-unit-product = $\cdot$}
%\sisetup{per-mode = fraction}
\sisetup{per-mode = symbol}%choose one or the other
%END SIUNITX STUFF

%NEW COMMANDS
\providecommand{\e}[1]{%scientific notation command
  \ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{%absolute value command
  \left|#1\right|
}
\newcommand{\tablesection}[1]{%new section in 2-column table
  \rhead{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1} \\
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{#1} \\
  \midrule 
}
\newcommand{\tablesubsection}[1]{%new subsection in 2-column table
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2}
}
\newcommand{\notabene}[1]{%use to add multicolumn notes & stuff for a 2-column table
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
      \textbf{N.B.} {#1}
    \end{minipage}} \\
}
%END NEW COMMANDS

%MISC DOCUMENT SETTINGS
\setlength\parindent{0pt}%removes paragraph indentation
\setlength\parskip{0em}%remove line spacing for table of contents

%BEGIN DOCUMENT PROPER
\begin{document}
%table of contents & similar
\tableofcontents

\setlength\parskip{1em}%uses default paragraph spacing after T.O.C.

\include{foo}
```

`foo.tex` file:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
  \tablesection{Chapter 4: The Laws of Motion}
  \tablesubsection{General Motion Formul\ae}

  \(F_g = G\displaystyle\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}\) & The magnitude of the gravitational force $F_g$ where $G = \SI{6.67e-11}{\newton\meter\squared\per\kilo\gram\squared}$ is the universal gravitation constant, and $r$ is the distance between the two objects with masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ \\
\end{longtable}
```

An interesting development: This will not compile in either `TeXWorks` or `emacs` with `auctex`, however it *will* compile with warnings on [Overleaf](http://overleaf.com/). Another interesting development: Overleaf requires `\sisetup{inter-unit-product = $\cdot$}` while both `TeXWorks` and `emacs` will not compile unless `\sisetup{inter-unit-product = \cdot}`

Comment: Well I get an `! Undefined control sequence.` because of the `\e`, so I have some doubts that your example is a "real" example. Did you really try exactly the code you described?

Comment: sorry about that, `\e` is defined as `\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times10^{#1}}}`

Comment: The posted code produces no error in texlive 2014 or 2015.

Comment: why have `\displaystyle` in the middle of the math expression? it's not an error but it's slightly odd, as it affects the whole expression, not just the following frac.

Comment: the error message shown is could not be generated by the code shown as `.newton\meter\squared\per\kilo\gram\squared}` is not on line 5.

Comment: the `\displaystyle` allows for expressions to be the size of `\[ \]` expressions when inside a `\( \)` size environment. I use it when I want a larger fraction that is inline, though if there's a better way I wouldn't be surprised. If the error isn't on line 5, I'll look at some of my table formatting stuff on preceding lines (not shown in the MWE), but I didn't think that was causing any errors.

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the version information this places into the `.log` into the question.

Comment: BTW, the error you've put in the question doesn't look like a 'raw' one from TeX. Can you edit the real message from the `.log` file into the question?

Comment: @JosephWright added pastebin links for the `pdflatex` generated log and the log from the emacs output buffer

Comment: @5donuts That's not the log for the example you've posted: to track this down we really do need a minimal example showing the problem and a matching log file.

Comment: @JosephWright Due to assumptions and poor question etiquette on my part (as well as a bit of laziness) I incorrectly identified the problem as being related to `siunitx` and provided a MWE which did not actually replicate the issue. Now trying to replicate the issue by adding what I thought was causing the answer based on David Carlisle's answer, I am again unable to reproduce the issue, and for this I apologize. I should have made sure that the MWE produced the issue instead of assuming such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer pertains to the updated version of the query, in which the OP provided specifics regarding the options used when setting up the `siunitx` package.)

The instruction

```
\sisetup{inter-unit-product = $\cdot$}
```

is incorrect. It should be

```
\sisetup{inter-unit-product = \cdot}
```

With this modification, your example code compiles correctly.

Comment: `\e` is `\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times10^{#1}}}`, but I did not know that `siunitx` had an "e" notation

Comment: @5donuts - Another advantage of using `\SI{}{}` is that it gives you the correct spacing between the numeric part and the units part. No need to fiddle with `\,` and other spacing directives.

Comment: Even after changing the line to `$G = \SI{6.67e-11}{\newton\meter\squared\per\kilo\gram\squared}$`, the compiler pulls the same error. I'm still not sure of what is causing the error, other than it is related to long chains of `siunitx` macros, because short statements such as `\SI{1}{\newton}` compile without errors, while long statements such as `\SI{6.67e-11}{\newton\meter\squared\per\kilo\gram\squared}` cause errors, but I'm not sure why, because I did not have this issue until recently.

Comment: @5donuts - please post the entire table that's giving you these problems. Please also state which TeX distribution and which operating system you use.

Comment: made some changes, sorry for the late response. Hopefully this helps find the solution.

Comment: @5donuts - The instruction `\sisetup{inter-unit-product = $\cdot$}` is incorrect. It should be `\sisetup{inter-unit-product = \cdot}`.

Comment: that fixed the problem, many thanks! If you make your comment an answer, I'll flag it as the solution.